# Static HttpClient still creating TIME_WAIT tcp ports

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I am experiencing some interesting behavior with the HttpClient from the .NET Framework (4.5.1+, 4.6.1 and 4.7.2). I have proposed some changes in a project at work to not dispose of the HttpClient on each use because of the known issue with high TCP port usage, see https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/.

I have investigated the changes to check that things were working as expected and found that we are still experiencing the same TIME_WAIT ports as before.

To confirm that my proposed changes were correct I have added some extra tracing to the application that confirm that I am using the same instance of the HttpClient through out the application.  I have since used simple test application (taken from the aspnetmonsters site linked above.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
        private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(handler);
        public static async Task Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting connections");
            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
            {
                var result = await Client.GetAsync("http://localhost:51000");
                Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Connections done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue only occurs when connecting to a site that is hosted in IIS using Windows Authentication.  I can reproduce the issue easily by setting the Authentication to Anonymous (problem goes away) and back to Windows Authentication (problem reoccurs).

The issue with Windows Authentication does not seem to be limited to the scope of the provider.  It has the same issue if you us Negotiate or NTLM.  Also the issue occurs if the machine is just a workstation or part of a domain.

Out of interest I created a dotnet core 2.1.0 console app and the issue is not present at all and works as expected.

TLDR: Does any one have any idea on how to fix this, or is it likely to be a bug?

Comment: There's no "known issue with high TCP port usage". That article says that you *don't* need to dispose of HttpClient because it's reusable and thread-safe. It also says that you *shouldn't* dispose it because it can reuse SSL channels, sockets etc, the way WebClient and  raw HttpWebRequest do. You use a static HttpClient because you can, not because of any issues

Comment: 'There's no "known issue with high TCP port usage"'.   That article seems to argue the point differently.  It's not a bug as it's intended behavior and the recommendation is to not dispose of the HttpClient every request.  Even Microsoft Patterns and Practices recommends the same configuration as well.  By simply running the sample application against IIS with Windows Authentication you can see the issue.  Use TcpView from sysinternals and you can see 1 port left in TIME_WAIT per request.

Comment: No it doesn't. It doesn't say there's a problem with HttpClient - it doesn't even imply it. It says you can reuse the HttpClient instance and save some sockets. It's not something new either, this was known since 2012. That article though is probably the most popular these days

Comment: BTW no repro. Running the article's code behaves as expected. Using TcpView shows that using a static HttpClient doesn't leave any sockets. Running it with a new HttpClient each time does leaves 10 sockets open. I had to wait for those sockets to close before running the test with a static client

Comment: Furthermore, using a static client resulted in *far better* performance because it didn't have to performe a DNS lookup and establish an SSL channel each time. Forget the sockets. This was a 100x improvement. *That* should be enough to convince anyone to use a shared HttpClient instance, especially if you make a lot of HTTP calls

Comment: Instead of just using a shared HttpClient though I'd suggest you use HttpClientFactory, especially in .NET Core 2.1. It takes care of reusing and cleaning up HttpClientHandlers, the classes that actually create the connections and make the calls. Periodic cleaning is required to take care of DNS updates. Check [HttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore). The explanation applies to .NET Core in general

Comment: You should also check Scott Hansleman's article series on HttpClientFactory. Eg [Adding Resilience and Transient Fault handling to your .NET Core HttpClient with Polly](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddingResilienceAndTransientFaultHandlingToYourNETCoreHttpClientWithPolly.aspx) shows how you can combine HttpClientFactory and Polly to create HttpClient instances that eg retry automatically in case of error and stop trying after a while

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when you tested did then endpoint you are connecting to use Windows Authentication?  and the HttpClient pass in the credentials via the HttpClientHandler?  When using no authentication on an endpoint it works fine for me as well.

Also this only effects .NET Framework and not dotnet core.

Comment: I called a service with Windows Authentication and reproduced what you describe. This isn't a bug in HttpClient though. NTLM needs to authenticate each connection, which means that by default, each request creates a new connection unless [UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.unsafeauthenticatedconnectionsharing(v=vs.110).aspx) is set. In the "full" framework HttpClient uses HttpWebRequest which uses WinHTTP and that behaviour.

Comment: In .NET Core 2.1 though HttpClient is completely rewritten and avoids creating new connections by pooling connections and [handling the NT authentication flow itself](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/AuthenticationHelper.NtAuth.cs). The same code runs on Windows and Linux now, while up to Core 2.0 it would call WinHttp on Windows and libcurl on Windows. You can chase the calls from HttpClient to SocketsHttpHanlder to HttpConnectionPoolManager , HttpConnectionPool, HttpConnection to  AuthenticationHelper.NtAuth.

Comment: Long story short, you'll have to use the .NET Core 2.1 class and the new SocketHttpHandler if you want to reuse NTLM-authenticated connections. Another option would be to use WebRequestHandler and set the [UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler.unsafeauthenticatedconnectionsharing(v=vs.110).aspx). The documentation for [HttpWebRequest.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.unsafeauthenticatedconnectionsharing(v=vs.110).aspx) explains risks and precautions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short version**

Use .NET Core 2.1 if you want to reuse connections with NTLM authentication

**Long version**

I was quite surprised to see that the "old" HttpClient does use a different connection for each request when NTLM authentication is used. This isn't a bug - before .NET Core 2.1 HttpClient would use HttpWebRequest which closes the connection after every NTLM authenticated call.

This is described in the documentation of the [HttpWebRequest.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.unsafeauthenticatedconnectionsharing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property which can be used to enable sharing of the connection :

> The default value for this property is false, which causes the current connection to be closed after a request is completed. Your application must go through the authentication sequence every time it issues a new request.
>
> If this property is set to true, the connection used to retrieve the response remains open after the authentication has been performed. In this case, other requests that have this property set to true may use the connection without re-authenticating.

The risk is that  :

> If a connection has been authenticated for user A, user B may reuse A's connection; user B's request is fulfilled based on the credentials of user A.

If one understands the risks, and the application *doesn't* use impersonation, one could configure HttpClient with a [WebRequestHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the  [UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler.unsafeauthenticatedconnectionsharing(v=vs.110).aspx), eg :

```
HttpClient _client;

public void InitTheClient()
{
    var handler=new WebRequestHandler
                { 
                    UseDefaultCredentials=true,
                    UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing =true
                };
    _client=new HttpClient(handler); 
}
```

WebRequestHandler *doesn't* expose the [HttpWebRequest.ConnectionGroupName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y3d5dts(v=vs.110).aspx) that would allow to group connections eg by ID, so it can't handle impersonation.

**.NET Core 2.1**

HttpClient was rewritten in .NET Core 2.1 and implements all the HTTP, networking functionality using sockets, minimal allocations, connection pooling etc. It also handles [the NTLM challenge/response flow](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/AuthenticationHelper.NtAuth.cs) separatelly so the same socket connection can be used to serve different authenticated requests.

If anyone is interested, you can chase the calls from HttpClient to SocketsHttpHanlder to HttpConnectionPoolManager , HttpConnectionPool, HttpConnection, AuthenticationHelper.NtAuth and then back to HttpConnection to send the raw bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can see that the best course is to migrate to .NET Core.  I had a suspicion that it was by design rather than a bug, it's good to know though.

Comment: Insightful explanation

Comment: I can confirm the mentioned changes between .NET Framework and .NET Core.

I raised an issue at GitHub for clarity: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/74078
And here I published an example where I was able to reproduce and mitigate the issue: https://github.com/rgueldenpfennig/HttpClientImpersonation

The .NET versions after .NET Framework have greatly improved in that sector.