# Single Instance of HttpClient with UseDefaultCredentials

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, singleton, httpclient

I have been trying to update my API call using the suggestion from here 
to only have 1 instance of HttpClient. https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/#

This works fine and I have my do not use up all of the ports, however when I try to create a HttpClientHandler to pass along the default credentials my ports start being used up again. My API is setup to use Windows Auth for security reasons so I need to pass along the app pools credentials for a successful call.

Here are the 2 code blocks

```
    public static class WebApiCallUtility
    {
        private static HttpClientHandler _handlerNoCred = new HttpClientHandler();
        private static HttpClient _clientNoCred = new HttpClient(_handlerNoCred);

        private static HttpClientHandler _handlerCred = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
        private static HttpClient _clientCred = new HttpClient(_handlerCred);

        //Working ports are not used up
        public static HttpResponseMessage SendHttpGetRequestNoCred(string webApiUrl, string logSourceName, string subId)
        {

            _clientNoCred.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _clientNoCred.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage result = _clientNoCred.GetAsync(webApiUrl).Result;

            return result;

        }

        //No working tons of ports open hanging out with TIME_WAIT status
        public static HttpResponseMessage SendHttpGetRequestCred(string webApiUrl, string logSourceName, string subId)
        {

            _clientCred.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _clientCred.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage result = _clientCred.GetAsync(webApiUrl).Result;

            return result;

        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also provide a dump of fiddler or something that shows the requests sent when you have the TIME_WAITS?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to revolve this issue buy using a different handler type

```
    private static WebRequestHandler _handlerCred = new WebRequestHandler
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true
    };

    private static HttpClient _clientCred = new HttpClient(_handlerCred);
```

I found this answer here [Static HttpClient still creating TIME_WAIT tcp ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236268/static-httpclient-still-creating-time-wait-tcp-ports)