# Migrating code using WebRequestHandler to .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

I have a project that targets .NET Framework 4.8 and I want to migrate it to .NET Standard 2.0. I have problem with updating this method:

```
        private static HttpClient CreateHttpClientItem(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout, HttpMessageHandler messageHandler)
        {
            messageHandler = messageHandler ?? new WebRequestHandler
            {
                Credentials = new CredentialCache
                {
                    { uri, "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials }
                },
                AllowAutoRedirect = true,

                UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true
            };

            return new HttpClient(messageHandler)
            {
                BaseAddress = uri,
                Timeout = timeout
            };
        }
```

I can't use HttpClientHandler instead of WebRequestHandler because of this issue [Static HttpClient still creating TIME_WAIT tcp ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236268/static-httpclient-still-creating-time-wait-tcp-ports). I can't migrate to .NET Core 2.1 because other things developed in .NET Framework 4.8 depend on that project. Is there any workaround to fix this issue?